# How to Navigate from one activity to another along with data?

Tags: android

I am in Activity A, now I navigate to Activity B. After I complete my work in Activity B, I switch back to Activity A(calling the finish(); function in onclick() event of a button). This finish(); function takes me back to Activity A by resuming Activity A. How can I navigate from Activity B to A along with the data.

here is the code:-
Activity A:-

NewMain.java

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore state members from saved instance

        alarmname1 = savedInstanceState.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE");
        range1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("EXTRA_MESSAGE_RANGE", 100);
        //Toast.makeText(NewMain.this, longi1, 2000).show();




    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){   

                 /*Bundle bu_lati = getIntent().getExtras();
                    lati1= Double.parseDouble( bu_lati.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LATITUDE"));
                    Bundle bu_longi = getIntent().getExtras();
                    longi1=Double.parseDouble( bu_longi.getString("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LONGITUDE"));
                    */

                 Bundle lati1=data.getBundleExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LATITUDE");   
                 Bundle longi1=data.getBundleExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LONGITUDE");
             }
             if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
                 //Write your code on no result return 
             }
          }
        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.newgui1);

         alarmname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         range=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        im1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        Button lnl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //alarmname

                alarmname1=alarmname.getText().toString();
                //range


                range1=Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());

               Intent myIntent = new Intent(NewMain.this, NewMain2.class);
              myIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", alarmname1);
              myIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_RANGE", range1);
              myIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LATITUDE1", lati1);
              myIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LONGITUDE1", longi1);
              NewMain.this.startActivity(myIntent);

           }
         });

        lnl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Toast.makeText(NewMain.this, longi1, 2000).show();



            }
         });
        im1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent myIntent = new Intent(NewMain.this, MapViewDemo.class);
              NewMain.this.startActivity(myIntent);

           }
         }); 
        }

    }
```

Activity B:-

```
MapViewDemo.java



public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
            {   
                //---when user lifts his finger---
                if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
                    GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
                    lati=p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
                    longi=p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), lati+ "," +longi, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }                            
                return false;
            }        

        } 

            Button buttondone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndone);
            buttondone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent();

                     myIntent1.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LATITUDE", lati);
                     myIntent1.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LONGITUDE", longi);

                     setResult(NewMain.RESULT_OK, myIntent1);
                    finish();




                }
             });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your B activity like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

before finish B activity setResult() like,

```
Intent i =new Intent();
    i.putExtra("yourdata", "abc");
    setResult(2, i);
    finish();
```

on your A activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==2){
        String s = data.getStringExtra("yourdata");
    }
}
```

this way you can pass data from child activity to parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use the pattern [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) that takes an Intent and a request code as parameters.

Is the same of startActivity but you can wait a result when activity B finish.

Before call finish of activity B you have to use [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) on activity B and then finish(). setResult takes 2 parameters: an intent (data that you want to pass back to A) and a resultCode (ok, error codes).

On activity A you can wait and grab the result overriding method [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

Here's a good tutorial: [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

pass requestcode from your activity newMain and use `startActivityForResult` instead of
 `NewMain.this.startActivity(myIntent)`:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
```

now make your `(requestCode == 10)` in your if condition.

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.
To start 2nd activity:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(NewMain.this, MapViewDemo.class);
startActivityForResult(launchNewIntent, 2);
```

In activity A

```
    int result1 ;
int result2 ;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            result1=data.getExtras().getInt("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LATITUDE");
            result2 =data.getExtras().getInt("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LONGITUDE");
        }
    }
}
```

In activity B

```
        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent();
    myIntent1.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LATITUDE", lati);
    myIntent1.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE_LONGITUDE", longi);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) and you will understand the whole concept..